# CoreData MagicalRecord save methods crashes on iPhone5

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, magicalrecord

Currently I'm working with `MagicalRecord v2.3.0-beta.3 commit:d18e74fe435359238b9593c03e41c1ee0baa0b78` framework. I'm getting 1 a crash log (from `Crashlytics`) on iPhone 5 all the time. App is still in development. The crash log looks like below:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x38eee626 objc_msgSend + 5
1  Foundation                     0x2f06d02d -[NSError dealloc] + 60
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x38ef3b6b objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 174
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x38ef40d3 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 358
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2e67d481 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
5  Foundation                     0x2f0778e3 -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 122
6  CoreData                       0x2e4bdfbf -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 942
7  MyApp                          0x00162f9f __70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke15 (NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalSaves.m:82) // here app crashes
8  CoreData                       0x2e5219cd developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 88
9  CoreData                       0x2e521b13 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 114
10 MyApp                          0x00162e51 -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:] (NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalSaves.m:116)
11 MyApp                          0x000a2b0d -[SPNCoreDataHandler parseAndSaveDictionaryReturnOperationArray:withSaving:] (SPNCoreDataHandler.m:70)
12 MyApp                          0x00078f21 __102-[SPNApiHandler getAllDataWithDownloadingSuccessBlock:savingSuccessBlock:downloadStatus:failureBlock:]_block_invoke (SPNApiHandler.m:69)
13 MyApp                          0x000795b9 __66-[SPNApiHandler sendGetRequestWithPath:successBlock:failureBlock:]_block_invoke (SPNApiHandler.m:174)
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x393cdd53 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x393cdd3f _dispatch_client_callout + 22
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x393d06c3 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 278
17 CoreFoundation                 0x2e714641 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
18 CoreFoundation                 0x2e712f0d __CFRunLoopRun + 1308
19 CoreFoundation                 0x2e67d729 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
20 CoreFoundation                 0x2e67d50b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
21 GraphicsServices               0x335ec6d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
22 UIKit                          0x30fde871 UIApplicationMain + 1136
23 MyApp                          0x0009c347 main (main.m:16)
```

And here's code which I wrote:

**NOTE:** I removed some parts of this method for sake of readability (that's why method returns void instead of NSArray).

```
- (NSArray *)parseAndSaveDictionaryReturnOperationArray:(NSDictionary *)dictionary withSaving:(BOOL)saveSynchrounously {

    [self truncateAll]; //method which removes all entries in coreData

    /* methods below creates entities from array given in dictionary
       using [NSManagedObject MR_createEntity] method 
       e.g. Contact *contact = [Contact MR_createEntity]; */

    [self saveContacts:dictionary[@"contact"]];
    [self savePeople:dictionary[@"person"]];
    [self saveBuildings:dictionary[@"place"]];
    [self saveSessions:dictionary[@"session"]];
    [self saveLectures:dictionary[@"program"]];
    [self savePartners:dictionary[@"partners"]];
    [self saveSponsors:dictionary[@"sponsors"]];
    [self saveExhibitorsPlans:dictionary[@"exhibitorplan"]];
    [self saveMeetingPlans:dictionary[@"meetingplan"]];
    [self saveOrganizationalInformation:dictionary[@"info"]];

    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

    //continue executing method...
}
```

I tried also to use `[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:]` method but it crashes too.

In other Stackoverflow question someone suggested, that crash can be caused by deleting, creating and saving to many entities at once. In my case it's around 200 deleted entities + 200 new ones. Can it cause crash?

On other devices (iPhone 4s, iPhone 5s, iPad 2, iPad4, iPad mini) it works fine. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you calling save from the main thread?

Comment: like is your parseAndSaveDictionaryReturnOperationArray being called from a background thread perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out what was going on. Tester didn't delete and install an app as I told. Crash appears because DB schema changed. Maybe I should start to think about DB versioning during development to avoid those kind of issues.

Thanks anyone for answers.